# Route user to some file like: index.php from any folder which is not having index.php | using .htaccess

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, web

I have this code in my `.htaccess` file to route the user to my `root/index.php` file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

However, this works fine: So if i am going to `localhost/MyFolder/Xyz` and if `Xyz is not existing it takes me to localhost/index.php` Now what i want is, I have folders like `css` `js` `images` so I don't have any `index.php` file there, so it lists all my files. I know I can add index.php file there and can redirect user to my root. But this is a TDS job. Is there any way that i can do something in `.htaccess` and whereever in any folder if it is unable to find the `index.php` it takes me to `index.php` of `localhost`?

Is there a way to do is. Just don't want to put `index.php` in each and every folder to restrict its access.

Answer (score 0):

What you basically want is to avoid listing all files of a folder when there is no index file.

You can achieve this by adding this to your .htaccess file:

```
Options All -Indexes
```

Comment: Ok this thing doesn't shows the files of my directory. Now is there any way that i could redirect the user to some `link`??

Comment: Also after doing this it won't show me the sub-directories but it gives me Error 500. Which i don't want. So if i could redirect the user to so `link` that will do the needful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think what you want is to simply remove the Rewrite Conditions from your .htaccess file. Those rewrite conditions tell Apache to NOT redirect if the path entered is that of a file or a directory.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

That's it.